# Full width nav tabs in bootstrap 4 alpha

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello how can make my **nav-tabs** full width, I tried using `width:100%;` to no avail.
[image]

here's the html code that i used.

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#learn" role="tab">Learn More</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#faq" role="tab">Frequently Asked Questions</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Need more code or woking example

Comment: uhhh. that is the exact code. i tried .nav-tabs{text-align:center} it dosen't work so i didn't include it. and other methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per I understood you want to `width:100%` to `<ul class="nav nav-tabs">` right? 
But by default `<ul class="nav nav-tabs">` is in `width: 100%` you do not need to give css to `<ul>` but if you want to `width: 100%` to `<li class="nav-item">` then give css to it like this:

```
  .nav-item {
     width:100%;
   }
```

or else instead of `text-align: center` give `<ul class="nav justify-content-center">` to your `html`.

Answer (score 12):

There are build-in css classes to achieve this. From official [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#fill-and-justify):

> To proportionately fill all available space with
>   your `.nav-items`, use `.nav-fill`. Notice that all horizontal space is
>   occupied, but not every nav item has the same width.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#learn" role="tab">Learn More</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#faq" role="tab">Frequently Asked Questions</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

> For equal-width elements, use `.nav-justified`. All horizontal space
>   will be occupied by nav links, but unlike the `.nav-fill` above, every
>   nav item will be the same width.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#learn" role="tab">Learn More</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#faq" role="tab">Frequently Asked Questions</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

it might be helpful. **you do not need to give css to ul**.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h3>Tabs</h3>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <p><strong>Note:</strong> This example shows how to create a basic navigation tab. It is not toggleable/dynamic yet (you can't click on the links to display different content)</p>
  </div>

  <h2>Basic Nav-tabs</h2>

  <div class="container">
    <h3>Inline List</h3>
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```